# double to int16 (generation or conversion?)

Tags: matlab, double

```
fsamp = 2;
deltaf = fsamp/nfft;   % FFT resolution
Nfreqtimestwo = 128;  % Used below
Nsines = Nfreqtimestwo/2 - 1;   % Number of sine waves
fmult = [1:Nsines];  % multiplicative factor
freq_fund = fsamp/Nfreqtimestwo;
freq_sines = freq_fund.*fmult; 
omega = 2*pi*freq_sines;
r = int16(0);
for(ii=1:Nsines)
    r = r + cos((omega(ii)/fsamp)*(0:messageLen-1));   
end
```

This is the code I am currently using to create my input signal. However, the end result of `r` is a 32,768 array of doubles. Now I would like to do the best approximation of that using `int16`. However, I would like to note that amplitude doesn't really matter. For example, my best approach so far I think has been:

```
    fsamp = 2;
    deltaf = fsamp/nfft;   % FFT resolution
    Nfreqtimestwo = 128;  % Used below
    Nsines = Nfreqtimestwo/2 - 1;   % Number of sine waves
    fmult = [1:Nsines];  % multiplicative factor
    freq_fund = fsamp/Nfreqtimestwo;
    freq_sines = freq_fund.*fmult; 
    omega = 2*pi*freq_sines;
    r = int16(0);
    for(ii=1:Nsines)
        r = r + int16(8192*cos((omega(ii)/fsamp)*(0:messageLen-1)));   
    end
```

Are there any better ways to approach this?

**EDIT**
The reason I want to convert the doubles to ints is because this list is being used in an embedded system and eventually going to a 16-bit DAC... no doubles allowed

Comment: I would convert as the very last step, what you have now accumulates quantization error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int16(vector)` converts `vector` from `double` to `int16` and this is the preferred way. The alternate way of doing it is to define all your constants as `int16`s in which case, MATLAB will give you the result as an `int16`. However, this is cumbersome, so stick with what you have (unless if you *absolutely* have to do it this way).

Also, unrelated to your actual question, you can ditch the loop by using [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html). I'll leave that for you to try out :)

Comment: Really? I just chose the scalar 8192 pretty randomly... what's the tradeoff if I were to make that number bigger or smaller? The reason it's there at all is because almost all the numbers are between [-1,1] so directly making those ints lost practically all precision.

Comment: `int16` maxes out at `2^15 - 1`, so you ought to keep that in mind. Without being clear on _why exactly_ you want to convert from a `double` to an `int16`, there is not much I can say. An array of the size you have is peanuts for MATLAB on a decent machine and you practically won't notice any performance/memory difference between ints and doubles.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that to the question.